# Nested List Order In C#

Tags: c#

I have a custom list called ServiceFormFields and it has a List property named ChildrenTables.

I want to order descending by ChildrenTables' names

```
var fields = activeForm.ServiceFormFields.OrderBy (o => 
 o.ChildrenTables.OrderBy(c=>c)).ToList();
```

but it does not work.

I want to order ServiceFormFields list according to its children. Maybe I should do with GroupBy..

So, for example...

ServiceFormFields has FieldName property.. and Children is a List of String

1. FieldName = Matter, Children = Version
2. FieldName = Client, Children = Matter
3. FieldName = Status, Children = Null
4. FieldName = Version, Children = Null  (but has parents, it is Matter)

so and I want to order like:
2,1,3,4

because Client is the on highest level, second is Matter, third one is Version because Matter is its parent, and final is Status, because it does not have any dependency.

Edit: This is structure of the class

```
public class ServiceForm
{
    public List<ServiceFormField> ServiceFormFields { get; set; }

    public string Id {  get; set; }

    public bool IsDefaultPrimary { get; set; }

    public string Name  { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Type  { get; set; }

}


public class ServiceFormField
{

    public FormProperty FormField {get;set;}
    public bool IsVisible { get;set;}
    public List<string> ParentTables {  get; set; }
    public bool HasChildren { get; set; }
    public List<string> ChildrenTables { get; set;  }

}


public partial class FormProperty 
{               

    private string NameField;

    private string SQLInfoField;

    ...

 }
```

NameField contains Client, Matter, Version..

Comment: Could you provide related model?

Comment: What if it has many children, do you need it to appear multiple times?

Comment: If it has many children, it means it is on higher position.. This is actually a basic parent-child issue.. And I want to order parent fields s highest .. but  ServiceFormFields can contain many parent-children relations that are not related each other.. Some fields have dependency each other, but somefields not, and somefields have dependency with another fields.. so there is some groupping here

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you want, but here's a solution with the least bits of code needed.

I just transformed all the Childrens into a single string, and then the order by compares against them.

This is certainly not the most performance-wise solution, if this matters.

here's a sample:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ServiceForm sf = new ServiceForm();
    sf.ServiceFormFields = new List<ServiceFormField> 
    { 
        new ServiceFormField { ChildrenTables = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c"}},
        new ServiceFormField { ChildrenTables = new List<string> { "tra la la", "xxx"}},
        new ServiceFormField { ChildrenTables = new List<string> { "TTTTT" }},
        new ServiceFormField { ChildrenTables = new List<string> { "123455", "8157125", "1763123"}},
        new ServiceFormField { ChildrenTables = new List<string> { " ", " ", " ", "   "}}
    };

    var ordered= sf.ServiceFormFields.OrderByDescending(f => string.Join(",", f.ChildrenTables)).ToList();
    foreach(ServiceFormField sff in ordered)
    {
        foreach(string s in sff.ChildrenTables)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways, first you can use the List.Sort function with the signature Comparison like:

```
activeForm.ServiceFormFields.Sort(new Comparison<ServiceFormField>((e1,e2)=>Compare(e1, e2)));

private static int Compare(ServiceFormField e1, ServiceFormField e2)
{
    //Do your logic here      
}
```

in this case you will have an inplace sort.

or use the linq orderby function with the signature to KeySelector, an IComparer and implement an IComparer like that

var result = activeForm.ServiceFormFields.OrderBy(e => e, new ServiceFormFieldComparer());

```
public class ServiceFormFieldComparer : IComparer<ServiceFormField>
{
   private int Compare(ServiceFormField e1, ServiceFormField e2)
   {
      //Your logic here
   }      
}
```

in this case you will have an ordered list returned to you

Comment: Interestingly I was getting an exception about the list not have an IComparable implementation. I added both the generic and non generic, but kept getting it. I then abandoned this approach to the one I posted. But this is definitely a better solution.

Comment: @Swift, Apologies for the direct approach. I noticed you were involved in a previous Arabic SE site proposal. So I thought you may be interested to support a new one. Please spread the word to get wider support: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/123866/arabic-language?referrer=YTMyZTk3ZGFlNTNmYjkzZTEwNTQzOTliY2E2Mzc2NjkyNTQ2OGI1MTIwZTg0N2FjOTc5ZjBhYjY2MWIyZDEyOPCRDFRMom3erkhTvp1Unp-8PzXUk5iY7QYFks0TvDFu0